# I am creating a splash screen in java swing, how can I create a shape based window?

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I have managed to create a borderless window using `JWindow` and also a transparent window using the `setOpacity(`) function.

What I have left is to create a shape based window. I do not have any leads or ideas. If possible using `JWindow` as well

Comment: Have you tried the official tutorial [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) from the creators of Java (Sun/Oracle) ? Certainly there are many more online sources, including on this very site like [Java Shaped window with Outline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10676564/85421)

Comment: Thank you, let me try it then I will provide the necessary feedback

Comment: I just want to remember you from the [tour], which you apparently completed: "Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" -- you can search this site for `[java] [swing] shaped window` - [the results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+shaped+window)

Comment: For what it’s worth, Java already has a [SplashScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) class.

Comment: Please add code if you already have some.

Comment: Your idea worked and I was able to create a shape based window. Thank you